# Construction of Adams Spectral Sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

I'm reading the construction of Adams spectral sequence from *Adam's [Stable homotopy and generalised homology](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/Adams-SHGH.pdf)*. The construction of the SS is begun with the following description

> We start with $Y=Y_0$. Suppose $Y_p$ has been constructed. Let $W_p=E\wedge Y_p$. Then we can form the morphism
> $$Y_p\simeq S\wedge Y_p\xrightarrow{i\wedge 1} E\wedge Y_p=W_p$$Construct a cofibering $$Y_{p+1}\to Y_p\to W_p\to Y_{p+1}$$where $W_p\to Y_{p+1}$ has degree $-1$.

I couldn't understand how the cofibration sequence is obtained. If $Y_{p+1}$ is the cofiber(fiber) then how is another $Y_p$ at the left(right) hand side of the sequence obtained?

Comment: To say $W_p \to Y_{p+1}$ has degree $-1$ amounts to having a map $W_p \to \Sigma Y_{p+1}$.

Comment: Then do we begin with $Y_{p+1}\to Y_p\to W_p$ as a cofiber sequence? Does it follow from the fact that cofibrations and fibrations of a spectra are same?

Comment: Yes, define $Y_{p+1}$ to be the fiber of $Y_p \to W_p$.